# Azure Continous WebJob keeps running

Tags: azure, process, azure-webjobs

So My webjob runs on 10 instances, grabs 10 messages of the queue and processes them from what I can tell in my personal logs, but the webjob log never shows it finishing and the status continues to be "running" even though it should be finished. This job does run for awhile, about 45-60 minutes, since I'm syncing a ton of data for each call. I checked the process explorer and the thread says "Running" but when I look in the details I see below:

Process Explorer Example Here

[image]

Not sure what to do to make the job change its status to "Success" and continue on with the next item in the queue.

Another related issue, I'm using a ServiceBusTrigger but since the call is taking more than 5 minutes to complete, the next instance of the job picks up the same item from the queue again, so then I have 2 processes running the same message off the queue. It keeps doing this every 5 minutes until I maxed out my instance count available which is 10. Is there a way to stop this from happening? This may be related to issue above.

Comment: Hi @Mike, do you have any exceptions or debug info in your console output that will could help point to where your function is getting hung on? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/media/web-sites-create-web-jobs/webjobrundetails.png.

Comment: This ended up being an issue with sending in a string vs BrokeredMessage to the method in my job and then having to Complete the call to remove the message from the queue as soon as the job runs.

Comment: @Mike, that's good! Can you post an answer and it would be helpful for others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this, I had to add the following:

public async Task SyncTest([ServiceBusTrigger("syncqueue")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter log)

{

message.Complete();

}